# Is there a way to make debugger work with modified assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reflection, cil, mono.cecil

I am trying to modify assembly before using it. 
Main file:

```
using IlGenTestTarget;
using Lokad.ILPack;
using System.Reflection;
using Mono.Cecil;
using IlGenTest;

Assembly inAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class1));
AssemblyGenerator assemblyGenerator = new AssemblyGenerator();
byte[] b = assemblyGenerator.GenerateAssemblyBytes(inAssembly);
AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(new MemoryStream(b));
foreach (ModuleDefinition module in assemblyDefinition.Modules) {
    IlGenTestUtils.RemoveRemovedElements(module.Types);
    foreach (TypeDefinition type in module.Types) {
        IlGenTestUtils.RemoveRemovedElements(type.Methods);
        IlGenTestUtils.RemoveRemovedElements(type.Fields);
    }
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
assemblyDefinition.Write(ms);
byte[] res = ms.ToArray();
Assembly resAssembly = Assembly.Load(res);
Module resModule = resAssembly.GetModules()[0];
Type resType = resModule.GetType("IlGenTestTarget.Class1");
MethodInfo resMethod = resType.GetMethod("Method1");
resMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

IlGenTestUtils:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Collections.Generic;

namespace IlGenTest
{
    public class IlGenTestUtils
    {
        public static List<T> GetRemovedElements<T>(Collection<T> collection) where T : ICustomAttributeProvider
        {
            return collection
                .Where(t => t.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType.Name == "RemovedAttribute"))
                .ToList();
        }

        public static void RemoveRemovedElements<T>(Collection<T> collection) where T : ICustomAttributeProvider
        {
            foreach (T t in GetRemovedElements<T>(collection))
            {
                collection.Remove(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put breakpoint on Method1, everything works fine, but progam is not paused on it. When I invoke Method1 directly, without creating new assembly, program is paused on breakpoint as expected. Is there a way to make breakpoints work with dynamic assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The link between "source line at which a breakpoint is placed" and "assembly file contents" is defined by the `.pdb` file for the assembly. After modifying the assembly, I would actually be surprised if the link between them would still work.

You would need to also rebuild the `.pdb` file, which seems hard if not impossible.

Comment: Is there a way to get contents of pdb file from loaded assembly and link them to modified assembly? Also what happens when pdb file has reference to non existent method or type?

Comment: I have no experience with doing any of this. I know my limitations, this is all very low level, extremely specialized stuff.

Comment: You have to be sure that the pdb file and assembly file are always updated and aligned and inside the same folder. In visual studio there's a specilized window Modules which show you all the loaded modules, their path, wether the symbol file is loaded or not and eventually where VS is expected to find them

Comment: @128_bit_guy I think `Mono.Cecil` can write `.pdb` files out of the box. There is probably an option when writing the changed assembly.